# Can someone help me identify this font?

Tags: kanji

The font I am looking for [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFmfn.png) from this [site](http://www.thejapaneseconnection.com/free-kanji-symbols-customer/asian-japanese-kanji-symbol-aroma.htm) doesn't seem to name out the font. If someone could answer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about typography, not learning the Japanese language.

Comment: @istrasci Do we have an existing rule or discussion about this kind of questions?

Comment: I found [this meta question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/984/on-topic-or-off-topic-questions-about-fonts-and-their-usage). And looks like Graphic Design SE allows [font identification questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1083), although they don't explicitly say they welcome kanji fonts.

Comment: @naruto:  My reasoning is that knowing/not knowing that font will not help/prevent anyone from learning Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

It's [DF華康【かこう】楷書【かいしょ】体【たい】W5](http://www.fontfactory.jp/font/detail/df_kakoukaisho_w5/), designed by [ダイナコムウェア](http://www.dynacw.co.jp/dynafont/tabid/93/Default.aspx).